# atomic compare without locks or mutex

Tags: c++, compare, atomic

I'm trying to do an exercise which uses atomic operations. I want to do a comparison between a position of atomic array and an atomic int using `compare_exchange`. 
My code is:

```
std::array<std::atomic<long int>, 20> xx;
std::atomic<long int> number;
```

I want to do:

```
if (xx[i] > number)
  number = xx[i];
```

How can use `compare_exchange_weak()` in my case? I saw a lot of times http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `std::atomic` allows various atomic operations on a *single* object. To perform an atomic operation involving more than one object, you'll need a lock.

`compare_exchange`, as your link describes, atomically compares the object for equality with a *non-atomic* value, and updates it depending on that comparison. It doesn't compare two atomic values.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without lock?Because I know how doing with lock and mutex, but I'm trying to do it with only atomic operations...

Comment: @user3095097: Not in standard C++, and I'm fairly sure it's not possible at all on mainstream processors. You can only perform lock-free atomic operations on one object at a time.